# Удаление ненужного сертификата от letsencrypt

Tags: linux, letsencrypt

Был получен сертификат от [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) с помощью клиента [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Этот сертификат больше не нужен, как можно удалить его?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [документации certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#revoking-certificates) описано 2 шага для удаления сертификата:

- `certbot revoke --cert-path /etc/letsencrypt/live/CERTNAME/cert.pem` — удаляет информацию с серверов `letsenrypt`
- `certbot delete --cert-name example.com` — удаляет сертификаты и все симлинки на локальном сервере

Answer (score 1):

по поводу клиента *certbot* [в обсуждении](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/remove-domain-not-required-from-cert/14010) рекомендуют следующее:

1. создать (если ещё нет) резервную копию каталога `/etc/letsencrypt`:

   ```
   $ sudo cp -a /etc/letsencrypt{,.backup}
   ```
2. удалить каталоги и конфигурационный файл, относящиеся к удаляемому домену (в примере — `domain.tld`):

   ```
   $ sudo rm -r /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/ /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain.tld/ /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.tld.conf
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo certbot --delete -d site.com -d www.site.com
```

Comment: А чем это отличается от [уже существующего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686843/15479)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, что делает опция `--delete`.