# Как вернуть отозванный сертификат LetsEncrypt

Tags: letsencrypt, certbot

Некорректно перенес сайт с одного сервера на другой, 
на старом сервере сделал вот так:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686843/354320:

- certbot revoke --cert-path /etc/letsencrypt/live/CERTNAME/cert.pem — удаляет информацию с серверов letsenrypt
- certbot delete --cert-name example.com — удаляет сертификаты и все симлинки на локальном сервере

на новом заново получил сертификаты и теперь некоторые браузеры (скажем firefox) выдают ошибку SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE , некоторые открывают сайт нормально.

Причем https://www.ssllabs.com пишет что сертификат не отозван:
OCSP Must Staple    No
Revocation information  OCSP 
OCSP: http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org 
Revocation status   Good (not revoked)

Как сделать unrevoke данного сертификата?

Comment: Значит вы на самом деле используете старые сертификаты. Вы точно не забыли перезагрузить веб-сервер после получения новых сертификатов?

Comment: хром "видит" новый сертификат, яндекс браузер, сафари и фаерфокс показывает данные старого. Видимо потому что я в хроме данный сайт не открывал ранее.

Не могу никак "сбросить кеш" или что-то типа того в этих браузерах

При убирании галочки "Запрашивать у OSCP-серверов подтверждение текущего сертификата" в ФФ сайт открывается, в информации о сертификате старый сертификат с предупреждением о отзыве.

Как теперь пользователям сайта на него попадать - не понимаю. Старый сертификат действителен до января месяца :(

Comment: Под «хром "видит" новый сертификат» имеется в виду несовпадение отпечатка с таковым в фаерфоксе?

Comment: Да, в браузерах в которых сайт открывался ранее сертификат с датой создания 4 октября 2019 г.

в хроме (как и в сервисах онлайн проверки сертификатов) сегодня - 9 октября

Сбросить кеш, если это и возможно не вариант - пользователи это делать не будут, остается некий unrevoke

Comment: Старый сервер выключен/удалён или на нём всё ещё запущен сайт?

Comment: сайт там есть, но деактивирован в nginx, сертификаты удалены командой certbot delete

Comment: симлинка удалена с sites-enabled,  для внешнего мира сайта не существует на старом сервер, в общем

Comment: nginx не забыли перезапустить после «деактивации»?

Comment: да, и если бы он там и был никакого отношения к данному вопросу я считаю  это не имеет, сертификатов там нет, А записи ДНС уже давно обновлены по всему интернету и смотрят на новый сайт. открывая свой фаерфокс я попадаю на новый сайт, про старый можно забить.

Comment: Давно — это сколько? Записи ДНС могут оставаться старыми вплоть до недели, и у меня есть подозрение, что запросы всё ещё идут на старый сервер.

Comment: я вижу новый сайт, старого сайта нет, перезапускать нжинксы я умею, поверьте.

Comment: Наберусь наглости вам не поверить. Вы точно делали restart, а не reload?

Comment: Если коротко, то да, после того как полностью остановил старый сервер, страница в браузере не открылась, прописал в собственных хостах новый ип - все заработало

Если длинно - то для меня  загадка, я последовательно видел каждый шаг в браузере, как у меня "упал" старый сайт, как мой несконфигурированный новый сайт появился на 80м порту, как после того как добавил letsencrypt у меня появилась ошибка о отозванном сертификате.. каким образом запросы опять пошли на старый сайт, который не отвечал контентом, но почему-то "отвечал" сертификатами..

Comment: А не поделитесь ссылкой на сайт, если она не сверхсекретная? Вдруг у меня чисто случайно тоже окажется ошибка и я смогу её исследовать